# mod_rewrite removes the ?page= fine, get &id= not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got my .htaccess working that it is correctly going from:
`webshop/index.php?page=home` to `webshop/home`

If I put the id in the URL it still needs to be `webshop/product&id=1`. What I want to create is `webshop/product/1`.

I searched a lot of options on the internet but could not get it working. The code below is my .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Removes index.php from URL 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

# Rewrites /home to be /index.php?page=home
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^webshop/([^/]*)$ /webshop/?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Removes index.php from URL 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrites /webshop/product/1 to be /webshop/index.php?page=product&id=1
RewriteRule ^webshop/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ /webshop/?page=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

# Rewrites /webshop/home to be /webshop/index.php?page=home
RewriteRule ^webshop/([^/]*)$ /webshop/?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

You can change `(\d+)` to `([^/]+)` if your id is not only a number

Comment: Thank you! Works for me.